# Hadoop job DocumentDB dependency jar file

Tags: hadoop, azure-cosmosdb

I have a hadoop job which gets its input from azure documentdb. I have put the documentdb jar dependency files under a directory called 'lib'. However when I ran the job it gives me a ClassNotFound error message for one of the classes in the jar file. I also tried adding the jar files using the -libjars option but it didn't work either. Does anyone have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Mind posting the message included in the ClassNotFound exception? It'd be helpful to describe which class was not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class not found in Hadoop job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447465/class-not-found-in-hadoop-job)

Comment: Added answer in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447465/class-not-found-in-hadoop-job post, let's keep the post running in the original one.