# Class not found in Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-cosmosdb

I have a map reduce job which gets its input from DocumentDB. I've added to jar files under the lib directory in my source code and also user the -libjars when running the job. but I still get the class not found error for a class in the jar file. Here is some part of my driver program

```
public class MapReduceDriver extends Configured implements Tool  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MapReduceDriver(), args);
    System.exit(res);

}



@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf =  this.getConf();
    ....
```

When using the -libjars I once put the required jar files on the local driver and once on the hdfs but neither worked. How can I make sure that the -libjars works?

p.s. I'm using 2-node HDInsight cluster (running in Microsoft Azure).

Here is the error message I get

```
 Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.hadoop.DocumentDBInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1961)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getInputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:726)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.hadoop.DocumentDBInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1867)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1959)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Try putting the jar location to classpath and what else you have tried?

Comment: yes I've also added the jar file address to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable but it didn't worked.

Comment: Mind posting the message included in the ClassNotFound exception? It'd be helpful to describe which class was not found.

Comment: @aliuy: I posted the error message in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the DocumentDB Hadoop connector jar found here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop

The jar does not include dependencies. You can either have maven to retrieve dependencies for you, or manually download and include in the build path yourself.

Here are the dependencies:

- [Azure DocumentDB Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/releases)
- [OpenX Technologies JsonSerde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/releases)

Comment: I've already added the dependency jar files and the error I get is that the com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.hadoop.DocumentDBInputFormat class cannot be found, though it exist in the jar file which sits in a folder called 'lib' by my mapreduce driver class. As a matter of fact the same hadoop job runs on the HDInsight cluster on which I install the DocumentDB script! I wonder to know what the DocumentDB script does that I can do manually on my own cluster?

Answer (score 1):

HDInsight is using templton which doesn't have support for libjars, so you can't use that 
[templton docs](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/templeton_doc_latest/mapreducestreaming.html)

Also, I'm assuming you are building a custom HDInsight cluster using a powershell script.
You can copy all the jars with dependencies to 
HADOOP_HOME + '\share\hadoop\common\lib
this would be the hadoop lib folder.

Or you can directly use the powershell script published with changing the path that contains the dependency jars ( add your jars to an azure blob contains and just replace the path )
[powershell script](https://portalcontent.blob.core.windows.net/scriptaction/documentdb-hadoop-installer-v02.ps1.)