# Issue on Azure DocumentDB and Hive integrations on HDInsight using Microsoft Hive ODBC driver

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-cosmosdb

Could anyone please tell me if this is a known bug of Microsoft Hive ODBC driver?

> *Additional information: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error message: 'Error while
>   compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException
>   MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.hive.DocumentDBSerDe not found)'*.

I'm getting this error when performing a `SELECT` queries against hive external tables that points to documentdb collections.

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to copy the JAR dependencies to the Hadoop lib directory (HADOOP_HOME + '\share\hadoop\common\lib)

You can find a more info here: [Class not found in Hadoop job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447465/class-not-found-in-hadoop-job/)